# Добавить шрифт в imagettftext без создания ttf файла

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Проблема такая: в функции `imagettftext()` есть параметр  `$font` который определяет шрифт. Я хочу использовать довольно попсовый `Arial`, и при этом не создавать ttf файл с ним. Как это сделать. Вот весь код:

```php
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", 10000) . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0 , pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-type: image/png");

$random = rand(1000,9999);
$img = imagecreate(300,100);
$primaryColor = imagecolorallocate($img, 7, 188, 7);
$secondaryColor = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($img, 1, 128, 50, $primaryColor);
$font = "Arial";
imagettftext($ing, 10, 33, 100, 50, $secondaryColor, $font, $random);
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так нельзя, php (gd) не знает как искать файл шрифта по имени. Так что нужен путь!

**PS**

**`Arial` не бесплатен и требует лицензии для использования!** https://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/arial/licenses.

Есть куча свободных похожих шрифтов https://fonts.google.com/?category=Sans+Serif например https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans

Comment: Это не совсем ответ. Я имел в виду не указывать путь к `TTF` файлу, например в `CSS` можно просто `font-family: Arial, sans-serif`

Comment: @EugenEray Так нельзя, нужно путь!

Comment: Жаль. Я думал можно и без него.

Comment: @EugenEray Дополнил ответ до правильного.

Comment: Кстати: не хотел возиться с `dirname(__FILE__)` и решил сделать `$font = "/en/media/icoms/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf";` но так не работает.

Comment: `"/en/media/icoms/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"`  =>  `"./en/media/icoms/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"`    ||  
 `"/en/media/icoms/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"`  => `"en/media/icoms/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57501/discussion-between-e-p-and-eugen-eray).